# Cannot make a Visual Studio Code keyboard shortcut run a command line on the console

Tags: visual-studio-code, console, keyboard-shortcuts, org-mode

In Visual Studio Code, I would like to associate the execution of an OS command to a keyboard shortcut. In this particular case, I have an Org-mode file and I want to get a HTML output with the command:

```
pandoc -s text.org -o text.html
```

To do that, I wrote the following `keybindings.json` file, as required by VS Code:

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults
[
    // Generate HTML output from org-mode file:
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+p",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "args": {
            "text": "pandoc -s text.org -o text.html\u000D",
        },
        "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == org",
    }
]
```

Of these lines, I could check that the problem is in:

```
"text": "pandoc -s text.org -o text.html\u000D",
```

Everything else works: the "ctrl+alt+p" key is picked correctly, and the "when" condition is fine.

I tried to simplify the command, with a `type nul > test.html\u000D` in Windows, but no file has been created.

What is wrong in my script?

Comment: which text is send to the terminal?

Comment: @rioV8 - "pandoc -s text.org -o text.html\u000D"

Comment: If you eliminate the return `\u000D` is the right thing printed to the terminal and then hitting return runs it as expected?  And it just fails silently?

Comment: Try this :  `"pandoc -s 'text.org' -o 'text.html'\u000d"` - put quotes around the file names, perhaps your shell is interpreting those `.`'s as operators.

Comment: @Mark - Even without the `\u000D` special character, nothing changes.

Comment: @Mark - No change from quotations, either.

Comment: which text is shown in the terminal

Comment: @rioV8 - The command is launched through VS Code GUI, and it gives no feedback. However a new file should be created, but it is not.

Comment: You'll have to look at the pandoc documentation then to see if that script is correct.  This is a form I see the general form : `pandoc -s -o output.html input.txt`  so try `pandoc -s -o text.html text.org`

Comment: there has to be a terminal to send some stuff to, it does not happen in the background

Comment: @Mark - Pandoc works correctly with my syntax when I launch it manually from the command line. And the simpler command (`type nul > test.html\u000D`) has the same issues.

Comment: @rioV8 - I just want the output to go on a file, I do not need the terminal.

Comment: you need a shell to send the characters to, if there is no terminal the command does nothing, open a terminal and try the keybinding again